# Resharper command line tools not working

Tags: resharper

I am trying to use re-sharper command line tools. But I get an error which is highlighted . I am using only one solution. What could be the issue?
here is my command and responses

```
 PS D:\JERPOS\Tools\ResharperCommandLine> .\InspectCode.exe   -o="D:\temp
\Results.xml" -d --swea -x=EtherealCode.ReSpeller "D:\JERPOS\Code\POS Client\Jer.Pos.ClientStartup.sln"


JetBrains Inspect Code 2016.1.2
Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 4.0.30319.34209 under Microsoft      Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
 **Specify only one solution file**
Usage: InspectCode.exe [options] [project file]
Show help: InspectCode.exe --help
Enabled solution-wide analysis according to Inspect Code command line  Setting.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with the ReSharper Tools downloaded with nuget. The problem was the `-o` command, which it somehow failed to recognize.

changing `-o` to `--output` fixed it:

```
inspectcode.exe YourSolution.sln -output="D:\temp\Results.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably worked this out by now but I'm pretty sure it's due to the space in the path (even though it's quoted). I had a similar problem and fixed it by creating a symlink to the directory without a space in the name.